# Simple table th traversal and addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tr id=”thRow”>
   <th>   
  <th> 
  <th> 
  <th>
```

How do I traverse the ths above and addClass for these ths like first, second, third, fourth for each th inside JQuery –  (should be IE 8 compatible)

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you looking to add a unique class to each `<th>`?

Comment: Yes I need a unique class which I could add on dom ready based on if I need a 3 column table or a 4 column table... The problem is in one scenario I will only have 3 ths (ie I have just 3 column table) and in another I will have 4 ths (or 4 column table

Comment: Why do you need the classes? There might be a better solution for the problem you are trying to solve with the classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var arr = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'];

$('#thRow th').each(function(index){
    $(this).addClass(arr[index]);
})
```

Comment: This resolved my problem without having to add any extra check to determine column layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation for [`addClass(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) they have the following example:

```
$( "ul li" ).addClass(function( index ) {
  return "item-" + index;
});
```

so in your case it would be

```
$( "#thRow > th" ).addClass(function( index ) {
  return ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'][index];
});
```